# running Hue lights without Bridge?

Tags: philips-hue

Is possible to run the Phillips Hue lights without the bridge device?

I've been trying to search and see if the phillips hue bulbs can work without the hue bridge and just talk to it with a raspberry pi and a . Has anyone tried this yet?

Comment: Might be better asking this on one of the pi's IRC channels (or if SE network has a Pi site).

Comment: @ScottMcGready , thank you for the advice , but forget about the raspberry part , is it possible to run the lights without the bridge ?

Comment: I've no idea... try it and see? I saw some chat about hue bulbs in the Arduino IRC channel over at freenode a few weeks ago... might be worth looking through their logs.

Comment: @ScottMcGready thanks sir , i will check it

Comment: AFAIK they follow standard ZigBee protocol. At least other ZigBee lights are compatible with their bridge.

Comment: How did you go with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can manually pair the lamps with a LivingColors remote, a hue dimmer switch or a hue tap switch.